# It is a rare and (often heard, seldom heard) song

Tags: word-choice

I want to know which one would be the appropriate answer to this sentence:

> The session will include a playlist of her rare and .......... heard songs.

1. seldom
2. often

What I really need to know is that as you know rare here can mean exceptional and really good so in my opinion the answer is often.

Comment: *Rare* here is more likely to mean seldom heard.

Comment: 'Rare' _can_ mean 'exceptionally good', but I'm pretty sure it doesn't in this context.

Comment: The 'exceptionally good' idea is only an implication of 'rare', not really part of the primary dictionary meaning of 'rare' which is 'very very infrequent'.

Comment: If you say "the song is rare and often heard", then the *song* isn't rare, the *quality of the song* is rare. This missing information makes "the song is rare and often heard" sound either stupid or deliberately nonsensical. So deliberately nonsensical that I keep writing "the song is rare and oft heard", where "oft" is a deliberately out dated expression to indicate that I am choosing an artful phrase.

Comment: Words have default meanings. Choosing 'rare = unusually good / exceptional' in a sentence containing 'seldom/often heard' is at best tongue-in-cheek, at worst confusing / silly (violating at least one Gricean submaxim). Questions like this don't give room for the correct answer (The question itself is poorly framed).

Answer (score 1):

Either word might fit. To say there will be a playlist of her rare and seldom heard songs is grammatically correct; it will include those of her songs that are rare and seldom heard. On the other hand to say there will be a playlist of her rare and often heard songs would usually be understood as saying the playlist would include rare songs together with often heard songs.

Arguably though, to speak of "her rare and often heard songs" is contradictory, and the sentence should speak of "her rare songs and her often heard songs". For this reason, if you must insert a single word I would go with "seldom".

Comment: Any native speaker on hearing 'rare and often heard' would think either they or the speaker had had an aneurysm.

Comment: *Rare* sounds half-baked in this context,

Comment: @Mitch - Of course if you really emphasize ***AND***  it could make sense.